# Stop the deployment if any error in the servlet context listener

Tags: java, servlets, listener

I have issue with my application,

I have one listener and one filter in my application.

My application should not get deploy if any exception(checked or unchecked) in the ContextListener - contextInitialized() method.

Is there anyway to implement this?

I am using Weblogic server and i have tried the below options

1. System.exit(0) --> This is causing shutdown of the server
2. Throwing RuntimeException from the listener -->  This is causing shutdown of the server
3. Throwing unavailableException(Servlet) -- Doesn't help me.

Comment: This looks same but that didn;t answer my question

Comment: If it is executing some of your application, does that not mean that it has already deployed your application?

Comment: Its deployed my application eventhough there is an exception in the listener.